# How to make a button a user can only click once?

Tags: python, html, css, web, frontend

I'm making a website with html + css + python and I want to make a button where the user can click it but only once. Sort of like a like button on facebook. I don't have accounts for my users, but I was thinking of using cookies instead (less robust I know, but my website will be simple enough where this is fine).

Do you guys know how I can achieve this?

I've done a bunch of googling and trial and error, but nothing seems to work. My counter either doesn't increment, or it does but the value resets every time I reload the website.

Comment: set button disabled to true, on click event. you need to use some JS code for that,

Comment: Or your can make the button delete the data on the server that renders the page. So once the button is clicked there won't be any button anymore to click. This solution fits your requirements.

Comment: This has to be implemented server-side as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage mechanism:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
<button onclick='myOnClick()'>click here</button>
<script>
function myOnClick(){
  let myData = localStorage.getItem( 'myButtonStorage' );
  if ( myData == 'clicked' ) {
    alert ( 'already clicked' );
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem( 'myButtonStorage', 'clicked' );
    //
    // here do your action
    console.log ( 'do sth...' );
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I did something similar that sort of works with a createCookie and readCookie function, but how do I make sure all of my users get this timer updated for them live? Will I need to do something on my back end via Python Flask or is this achievable with just my index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to add the `disabled` attribute to the button when it's clicked, preventing it from being clickable.

```js
let oneUseButton = document.getElementById('one-use');

oneUseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  oneUseButton.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button id=one-use>you can only click this once</button>
```

Whenever you need to enable the button back, set `.disabled` back to `false`.